# what am i doing wrong in this bloom filter implementation?

Tags: c++, c, hash, bitarray, bloom-filter

I have this bit table for a segmented bloom filter. Here every column is managed by a single hash function.

```
unsigned char bit_table_[ROWS][COLUMNS];//bit_table now have 8*ROWS*COLUMNS bits
unsigned char bit_mask[bits_per_char] = { 0x01,0x02,0x04,0x08,
                                          0x10,0x20,0x40,0x80};
```

There are **ROWS** number of hash functions each of which handles the setting and checking of **COLUMNS*8** bits.

Elements are hashed and **bit_index** and **bit** are calculated as

```
compute_indices(unsigned int hash)
{
   bit_index=hash%COLUMNS;
   bit=bit_index%8;
}
```

Now insetion is done as

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i)
      {
        hash=compute_hash(i,set_element);
        compute_indices(hash);
        bit_table_[i][bit_index ] |= bit_mask[bit]; 
      }
```

And the query is

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i)
      {
     hash=compute_hash(i,set_element);
      compute_indices(hash);

      if (((bit_table_[i][bit_index])& bit_mask[bit]) != bit_mask[bit])
         {
            return false;
         }      
  }
```

My problem is the bloom filter gets full too soon and I suspect that i am not using the individual bits of the characters correctly. For example i suppose i should have something like:

**bit_table_[i][bit_index][bit]|=bit_mask[bit];**

for insertion but, since the **bit_table** is declared as two dimensional array i am not allowed to do this.

What should i do to make use of the individual bits of the char array?

English is my second language, so you might have trouble understanding my question. I would be happy to explain my points more if requested.

EDIT:
    **compute_hash(i,set_elemnt)** uses predefined salt values to compute hash value of the element to be inserted or queried.

Comment: Unrelated, but your English is good; just fix those `i` to `I` and `insetion` to `insertion` and you might as well be a native speaker. :)

Comment: Why are you doing the same bit `OR`ing and reading for _every_ row in `ROWS` in your filter?

Comment: @sarnold: The real code is very long, so i have tried to make it as simple as possible. Anyways please check my update

Comment: Thanks for trying to simplify things -- however, `hash` depends solely upon `i` in each iteration, and `compute_indices()` depends solely upon the value of `i` as well -- I have a feeling that your update doesn't accurately reflect what your code does. :/

Comment: You speak better English than most people I know :)

Comment: Are `bit_index` and `bit` global variables?

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your compute_indices method.

You are computing a column index and then apply a modulo 8 on this column index. At the end you will always use the same bit in a column.
For example for the column 10, you will always use the bit 2.

You should have :

```
compute_indices(unsigned int hash)
{
    int bitIndex = hash % (COLUMNS * 8);
    bit_index= bitIndex / 8;
    bit = bitIndex % 8;
}
```